# c# copying files to bin directory

Tags: c#

I'm able to have files put into the bin directory using the properties "copy if newer".

The problem I have is that I require a large number of dll files to be put along side my application. This means that my project becomes littered with a large number of files.

I'd like to put my files into an assets folder in my solution but have the files present in the bin directory on build. I have tried using post build events but I keep getting windows error codes (even when it's successful).

Is there an alternative way to have the external dlls accessible to my application?

Comment: There are lot of alternative ways. For example loading assemblies by hand using `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve`.

Comment: @PatrickHofman will this work for external assemblies that are referenced by other external assemblies?

Comment: What do you mean with 'external'? Assemblies are just assemblies, right?

Comment: @PatrickHofman We have a third party component. It has dlls. Those dlls also have references. When the 3rd party dlls calls those references will the event fire in my application?

Comment: But they are running in your app domain, right, so it should work.

Comment: sorry not sure if I asked the right question... I mean, When the 3rd party dlls calls it's own references  (which are also in the folder). Will the event fire in my application?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162418/discussion-between-prime-by-design-and-patrick-hofman).

Comment: You can [specify an assembly's location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/specify-assembly-location). Also see [probing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/probing-element) element.

Comment: Are you using an msbuild/ csproj file or are you using one of those new json based / buildfile less approaches?

Comment: @rene classic csproj

Comment: where are those dll 's you want to copy located, relative to your project file?

Answer (score 2):

If you [unload the project file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeKmO.gif)  you can edit the .csproj file.

Near the end you'll find:

```xml
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  -->
```

Lets modify that.

First define which [Items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171453.aspx) the AfterBuild task is going to copy. Notice that you only have to make sure these files exist on your disk in a folder (you say it is called assets) and are under source control. You don't need to include any of those files in your solution or project.

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- Include relative to this project file, so ..\assets would bring you to the solution folder 
         Take all files in the assets folder and subfolders, except *.txt files
    -->
    <Asset Include="assets\**" Exclude="*.txt">

    </Asset>
    <!-- take all *.txt files -->
    <TextAsset Include="assets\**\*.txt">
      <!-- meta data -->
      <SubPath>TextFiles</SubPath>
    </TextAsset>  
  </ItemGroup>
```

Now you'll have two Item collection, one called Asset and one called TextAsset. Those items can be consumed in build [Tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e54c37h.aspx). We are going to use the [Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e54c37h.aspx) task. I've commented the build script to explain what happens.

```xml
 <!-- this does what the name suggests-->
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <!-- log -->
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Start Copying assets"/>
    <!-- copy Asset files to one folder (flattens) -->
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(Asset)" 
          DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)"   />
    <!-- copy TextAsset files to a subpath, keep folder structure-->
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(TextAsset)" 
          DestinationFiles="@(TextAsset->'$(OutputPath)%(SubPath)\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" />
    <!-- done logging -->
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Copied assets"/>
  </Target>
```

Notice that I used the property `$(OutputPath)` which is one of the [well known properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629394.aspx). A similar list exists for [item meta data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164313.aspx).

The changes will not affect the operation of visual studio. Your changes will be preserved when adding or removing regular project items and/or project settings. As you'll keep this file in source control, also on your buildserver the same targets will be run, doing the same copy.

I prefer to test these build targets from the commandline, specifying only the target I'm interested in, like so:

```xml
msbuild Application2.csproj /t:AfterBuild
```

That gives you a much quicker round-trip time instead of doing a full build.